# copy constructor by address

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, copy-constructor

I have two copy constructors

```
Foo(Foo &obj){

}
Foo(Foo *obj){

}
```

When will the second copy constructor will get called?

Comment: it is my mistake the second one is not copy constructor 
just wanted to know when second function gets called?
Foo foo3(&foo0); solves it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Leaving aside that the second constructor isn't a copy constructor - you actually wanted to know when the second constructor will be called.*

The `Foo(Foo* obj);` constructor is a single parameter constructor - because it hasn't been marked with the `explicit` keyword, it provides an implicit conversion from `Foo*` to `Foo`. It may be called at any time where a `Foo*` is used in the place of a `Foo` or `const Foo&` - if it's being called unexpectedly, that's almost certainly what's happening.

In general, single parameter constructors should either be copy constructors (which other answers have explained) or should be marked `explicit`. Constructors which provide implicit conversions should be used sparingly.

Answer (score 10):

No you don't - you have one copy constructor

```
Foo( Foo * obj );
```

is not a copy constructor, and will never be used as such by the C++ compiler. You can of course use it yourself:

```
Foo a;
Foo b( & a );   // use your constructor
```

Note also that your real copy constructor should be declared as;

```
Foo( const Foo & f );
```

though the lack of const does not prevent it from being  a copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The second is not a copy constructor. It is a constructor that gets called when you create a new Foo object, giving a pointer to a Foo as parameter.

```
Foo foo0;
Foo foo1 = foo0;  // Calls copy constructor
Foo foo2(foo0);   // Calls copy constructor
Foo foo3(&foo0);  // Calls constructor taking a pointer as parameter
```

Comment: You could add the case Foo * pfoo = new Foo; Foo foo4(pfoo);

Answer (score 2):

One of your constructors is a copy constructor, the other is just a normal constructor.

The second will be called if you explicitly initialize a `Foo` from a pointer to `Foo` or in other situations where an conversion from a pointer to `Foo` to an r-value `Foo` is called for, such as argument passing and function returns.

It's usually a bad idea to have such an implicit conversion; it may occur when you don't expect it to and is liable to turn trivial typos from compile errors into unusual behaviour at runtime.